# Getting this error while installing DFX on my mac "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, decentralized-applications

this is what i wrote to install it  `DFX_VERSION=0.9.3 sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://sdk.dfinity.org/install.sh)"`

I have node 16.14.0 installed but whenever i  try this curl command or anyother curl command from other websites it shows that the certificate has expired[I am getting the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS39t.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we use curl which bundles with linux tools.
solution to this is uninstall it and install it (curl) again using  “sudo apt install”  linux command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).